# Should you bundle a JSON or CSV file with a webapp to store default data?

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase, csv, create-react-app

I'm making a React webapp where the user can chose from a list of default data in order to create a user modifiable copy of the data.

Currently, the data is in an excel file. I was planning on converting it to either CSV or JSON and simply put it in my public folder, but I'm wondering whether this is the right way. Would it be better to use an actual database? My app is deployed on firebase, I could upload my csv/json file to firebase storage or use firestore.

The excel file is rarely changing, that's why I thought best to simply put the data in the public folder.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data isn't being modified by users in any way, I don't see any reason to invoke extra database calls/activity.

Comment: So you recommended that I simply put the file in the public folder? Won't this slow down the initial load time, since the users will have to download the whole file? Should I leave it in csv or convert it to json?

Comment: Why would the users have to download it? Can't the data just live in a JSON file to be read from as needed, without needing to go in the public folder?

Comment: You mean that the json file should be directly included in the code?

Comment: Yes, I do something like this in an application to use as a seed database for new users: https://github.com/dylanesque/MPQChampApp